# What does MKErrorDomain code=3 mean when using the MapKit API?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am getting an error message when using the `MKDirections.calculate()` method that I don't understand.

I have looked through Apple's documentation but there is no mention on it. I have also searched using Google and still no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like as it's `MKErrorLoadingThrottled` [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkerrorcode/mkerrorloadingthrottled?language=objc)
See [MKErrorCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkerrorcode?language=objc) enum

> The data was not loaded because data throttling is in effect.
>   This error can occur if an app makes frequent requests for data over a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a way getting round this problem?

Comment: Consider refactoring/improving your logic, do you really need such frequent updates, maybe you can try monitoring location changes, and then re-calculate direction distance once delta is significant enough. Hope you get my idea.

Comment: Thanks but I have now found an alternative solution using Google's Cloud Platform to calculate distances without incurring a request limit penalty.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs

```
MKErrorUnknown = 1,
MKErrorServerFailure = 2,
MKErrorLoadingThrottled = 3,
MKErrorPlacemarkNotFound = 4,
MKErrorDirectionsNotFound = 5
```

`MKErrorLoadingThrottled` means, you are making too many requests within short period of time.

It could be either you call `MKDirections.calculate()` in a loop or you have a function calling `MKDirections.calculate()` based on a timer.

Comment: I am making calls to ```MKDirections.calculate()``` in a for loop where I am adding calls to a dispatch group for concurrent processing so maybe I need to find a way of pausing between consecutive calls.

Comment: yes, officially there isn't a posted limit,  but usually it fails after 50 requests, when I checked last time. That limit may have changed now.

Comment: So what happens when the limit has been reached? is there a way of restarting requests all over again until the limit is reached again?